# Forever start angular-http-server is not working

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to run angular dist in the background and I'm targeting the node_modules folder in the dist correctly and finding the angular-http-server library there. 
The terminal is not showing any error but it's not starting. I'm using this command:

```
forever start angular-http-server --host 'IP'
```

Is the command wrong? What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use it like this:

```
forever start node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --host {ip_address or domain} --prod
```

Change the ip_address or domain to the desired one

Answer (score 0):

with the command

`forever start node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve --host {ip_address or domain} --prod`

Show me an error:

`error:   Cannot start forever error:   script /home/ec2-user/angular01/backend-java-angular01/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng does not exist.`

Thanks for the help
PD: ng its working fine.
forever is installed
folder @angular/cli/bin/ng exits

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31054515)